# Why object changes into proxy object in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have have object problem is when I assign object to data property it converts into proxy object .

Here is what I am doing

```
 data() {
    return {
      msg: "",
      notifications: {},

    };
  },
  this.notifications =  TokenService.getUserInfo().unread_notifications;
```

Thats how I am receiving object

```
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(5)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

What is the reason?

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#proxied-objects. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64917686/1048572

Comment: "*I have have object problem*" - why do you have a problem with this, what doesn't work? Just use the proxy the same as you'd have used the object otherwise.

Comment: i want to use this object in v-for loop but  whenever it I get proxy object it for loop done't accept it

Comment: Describe what "doesn't accept it" means exactly please. Show the code and the error.

Answer (score 7):

Reason is Vue 3 is using [ES6 Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to make an objects reactive. You can study [how that works in depth](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#how-vue-tracks-these-changes) or you can just ignore it and work with objects as normal (Proxy is transparent wrapper and works everywhere as your original object)

Comment: **"Proxy is transparent wrapper and works everywhere as your original object"**

Except when it doesn't. For instance,a Proxy cannot be transferred between threads (i.e. Worker), which can make Vue a pain in the butt.

Comment: @Mud Just use `toRaw()`

Comment: TomTom Map requires map instance as raw non proxy object as well.