# Axios Get Request returned [Proxy proxy] - Flask & Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, proxy

I use component in a rendered page. Rendered page have an object array, it's `kpi_list[]`. I 'do axios get request' in rendering page.

```
     axios.get(URL + "/KPI/get_by_category/1").then(response=>{
          for (const data in response.data) {
              this.kpi_kalite.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data[data])))
              console.log(Object.values(this.kpi_kalite))
           }  
           .
           .
           .
```

Output:

```
(2) [Proxy, Proxy]
      0: Proxy {id: 1, base: 1, name: 'A', searchable_name: 'A', 
         user: '1', …}
      1: Proxy {id: 5, base: 1, name: 'B', searchable_name: 'B', 
         user: '1', …}
    length: 2
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

shouldn't I see it like this?

```
[
   {id: 1, base: 1, name: 'A', searchable_name: 'A', 
     user: '1', …},
   {id: 5, base: 1, name: 'B', searchable_name: 'B', 
     user: '1', …}
]
```

And whats is `[Proxy, proxy]`?

I send `kpi_kalite` array to component as a prop.
In component mounted, I try things like:

```
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.kpi_kalite[0]) 
    console.log(Object.values(this.kpi_kalite))
},
```

OUTPUT:

```
Proxy {id: 1, base: 1, name: 'A', searchable_name: 'A', user: 
       '1', …}
(2) [Proxy, Proxy]
```

There is a problem, right? These are not the objects or array of objects I need to see.

Comment: Are you using vue 3?

Comment: yes @NimaEbrazeh

Comment: In addition to @Cosimo Chelini answer, you can read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917686/vue-array-converted-to-proxy-object) which is the answer of you're question.

Comment: yeah it's work thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is normal!
vue 3 uses **proxies** to make the properties you define in the data **reactive**, consequently going to log the object you see the proxy that contains the **true value**.
to see the true value in console you should do like

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.yourValue)))
```

[if you want to read more](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#how-vue-tracks-these-changes)

Comment: You're right. thank you

Comment: please, mark as correct the answer so other users can see it

Comment: yeah but it said 'You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.' So, my reputation less than 15 :(