# In VueJs get proxy object instead my data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a logic in my Vue SPA app that pulls data from an API the first time a certain source is called. Since the process would be repeated frequently, I want to store this once pulled data set in my store js.

```js
export default {
  data() 
    return {
      data: ''
    }
  },
  //...
  async mounted() {
    if (store.myFetchedData) {
      this.data = store.myFetchedData;
    } else {
      this.data = await this.getDataFromApi()
      store.myFetchedData = this.data;    
    }
    console.log(this.data)
  },
  // ..
}
```

On the second run, I expect an object `{id: 1, name: "hello world",...}` to be output. Instead I get a proxy object.

```
Proxy { <target>: (3) [...], <handler>: {...} }
```

What does this proxy object mean? And what do I have to do to change that? Thanks in advance! Max

Comment: @JaromandaX You mean I should work with getters and setters, right?

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated my question. Data is a member var of the componente.

Comment: @JaromandaX `this.data` belongs to the Vue Component. Take a look to my updated code, please :-)

Comment: I see, you posted code that is not like the code you have an issue with - at least that's cleared up

Comment: @JaromandaX Now I understand you. That was my mistake. I don't mean data, of course, but this.data. I hadn't copied the code from my idea, but presented it here again in a more abstract way. Well done! I have corrected it. thank you!

Comment: Check the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202886/axios-get-request-returned-proxy-proxy-flask-vue-js

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata Thank you José! This link i very helpful :-) With all other comments and i found good answers i have a good overview what a proxy is.

Comment: did you tried ´console.log({ ...this.data }´